# Prevent aligned to override my font

Tags: math-mode, align, bold

I would like to write something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\mathbf{
        \begin{aligned}
            a
            \\
            f
        \end{aligned}
}$
\end{document}
```

and obtain both "a" and "f" bolded out.

Is there a way to tell the aligned environment (or any similarly-working environment) to not reset the math font specification i gave?

Comment: Use `\mathbf{a}` and `\mathbf{f}`.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\boldmath$
        \begin{aligned}
            a
            \\
            f
        \end{aligned}
$\unboldmath
\end{document}` also works (but doesn't make `a` and `f` upright, which I personally would like to call a benefit).

Comment: @Sigur, thanks but rewriting the style in every line is exactly what i would like to avoid.

Comment: @marmot are there also the analogous commands for \italics, etc? \italicsmath does not seem to work ...

Comment: @Squera If you use `\boldmath`, the fonts are already in slanted, so this wouldn't do anything. (I never use `\mathbf` myself because I personally consider the outcome a bit unfortunate.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a new math version which is bold, and then create a version of `aligned` that uses the new math version (`baligned`).  I also show the same modification for `tabstackengine` style macro approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\DeclareMathVersion{bxmath}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{bxmath}{OT1}{\familydefault}{bx}{n}
\newcommand\balignCenterstack[1]{{\mathversion{bxmath}\alignCenterstack{#1}}}
\newenvironment{baligned}{\mathversion{bxmath}\begin{aligned}}{\end{aligned}}
\begin{document}
\[
  \text{normal math}\begin{aligned}
            a\\f
        \end{aligned}\quad
  \text{bold math}\begin{baligned}
            a\\f
        \end{baligned}
\]
\[
  \alignCenterstack{a\\f}\quad
  \balignCenterstack{a\\f}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]